# What is plotted when string data is passed to the matplotlib API?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

```
# first, some imports:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

---

Let's say I want to make a scatter plot, using this data:

```
np.random.seed(42)
x=np.arange(0,50)
y=np.random.normal(loc=3000,scale=1,size=50)
```

Plot via:

```
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

I get this answer:

[image]

Ok, let's create a dataframe first:

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'x':x,'y':y.astype(str)})
```

(I am aware that I am storing `y` as `str` - this is a reproducible example, and I do this to reflect the real use case.)

Then, if I do:

```
plt.scatter(df.x,df.y)
```

I get:

[image]

---

**What am I seeing in this second plot?** I thought that the second plot must be showing the `x` column plotted against the `y` column, which are converted to float. This is clearly not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It's more obvious if the labels and locations are extracted, that the API plots the strings as labels, and the axis locations are 0 indexed numbers based on the how many (`len`) categories exist.
- [`.get_xticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticks.html) and [`.get_yticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_yticks.html) extract a list of the numeric locations.
- [`.get_xticklabels()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticklabels.html) and [`.get_yticklabels()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_yticklabels.html) extract a list of [`matplotlib.text.Text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text), `Text(x, y, text)`.
- There are fewer numbers in the list for the y axis because there were duplicate values as a result of rounding.
- This applies to any APIs, like `seaborn` or `pandas` that use `matplotlib` as the backend.

  - `sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='x_num', y='y', ax=ax1)`
  - `ax1.scatter(data=df, x='x_num', y='y')`
  - `ax1.plot('x_num', 'y', 'o', data=df)`

### Labels, Locs, and Text

```py
print(x_nums_loc)
print(y_nums_loc)
print(x_lets_loc)
print(y_lets_loc)
print(x_lets_labels)

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]

[Text(0, 0, 'A'), Text(1, 0, 'B'), Text(2, 0, 'C'), Text(3, 0, 'D'), Text(4, 0, 'E'),
 Text(5, 0, 'F'), Text(6, 0, 'G'), Text(7, 0, 'H'), Text(8, 0, 'I'), Text(9, 0, 'J'),
 Text(10, 0, 'K'), Text(11, 0, 'L'), Text(12, 0, 'M'), Text(13, 0, 'N'), Text(14, 0, 'O'),
 Text(15, 0, 'P'), Text(16, 0, 'Q'), Text(17, 0, 'R'), Text(18, 0, 'S'), Text(19, 0, 'T'),
 Text(20, 0, 'U'), Text(21, 0, 'V'), Text(22, 0, 'W'), Text(23, 0, 'X'), Text(24, 0, 'Y'),
 Text(25, 0, 'Z')]
```

### Imports, Data, and Plotting

```py
import numpy as np
import string
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import string

# sample data
np.random.seed(45)
x_numbers = np.arange(100, 126)
x_letters = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
y= np.random.normal(loc=3000, scale=1, size=26).round(2)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'x_num': x_numbers, 'x_let': x_letters, 'y': y}).astype(str)

# plot
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 3.5))
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='x_num', y='y', ax=ax1, title='X Numbers', rot=90)
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='x_let', y='y', ax=ax2, title='X Letters')

x_nums_loc = ax1.get_xticks()
y_nums_loc = ax1.get_yticks()

x_lets_loc = ax2.get_xticks()
y_lets_loc = ax2.get_yticks()

x_lets_labels = ax2.get_xticklabels()

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Matplotlib doesn't automatically convert `str` values to numerical, so your `y` values are treated as categorical. As far as Matplotlib is concerned, the differences '1.0' to '0.9' and '1.0' to '100.0' are not different.

So, the y-axis on the plot will be the same as `range(len(y))` (since the difference between all categorical values is the same) with labels assigned from the categorical values.

Since your `x` is a range equal to `range(50)`, and now your `y` is a range too (also equal to `range(50)`), it plots `x = y`, with y-labels set to respective `str` value.

Answer (score 3):

As per the excellent answer by dm2, when you pass y as a string, y is simply being treated as arbitrary string labels, and being plotted one after the other in the order in which they appear. To demonstrate, here's an even simpler example.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [5, 25, 10, 1] # these are ints
plt.scatter(x, y)
```

[image: plot with y given as integers]

So far so good. Now, different string y values.

```
y = list("abcd")
plt.scatter(x, y)
```

[image: plot with y as just some labels]

You can see how it just takes the y labels and just drops them on the axis one after another.

Finally,

```
y = ["5", "25", "10", "1"]
plt.scatter(x, y)
```

[image: plot with y having strings of integers]

Compare this with the previous results and now it should become obvious what's going on.